# export Outlook messages in hebrew to excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, email, microsoft-outlook, hebrew

I have thousands of emails in outlook which I would like to perform queries on in excel. I tried exporting to csv but all my hebrew characters appear as question marks. The only other export option I get in outlook is to a PST file which I didn't seem to find a way to open using excel.
I'm using outlook 2016 from office 365. 
Thank you very much.

Comment: Have you seen https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_excel-mso_winother/how-to-open-csv-file-of-hebrew-language/8963c913-fb3d-4f22-866e-d373366ba196

Comment: the problem though is that in outlook it isn't exported in UTF-8 so that data basically gets "lost" no matter which way I open the csv

Answer (score 0):

The [Message Report](https://www.reliefjet.com/Essentials/Features/OutlookReportMessages) tool will help you for sure. It can generate the report on your messages in any language. After that you can save it to UTF-8 CSV and open in Excel.

DISCLAIMER: I recommend this product because I'm one of the developers, so feel free to ask any further questions.